# How to use not in with conditions datetime

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, notin

i need show datetime select only. But show all datetime in table filesTA.

**this code:**

```
SELECT *
FROM filesTA tf
WHERE NOT tf.EmpNo 
IN (
SELECT lr.EmployeeRun
FROM LeaveRecord lr
WHERE lr.StartDate = '2012-10-01'
)
```

**Output:**

```
EmpNo | ChkDate | ChkIn | ChkOut
00001 | 2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2012-10-01 07:21:00.000 | 2012-10-01 12:21:00.000
00002 | 2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2012-10-01 08:13:00.000 | 2012-10-01 19:55:00.000
00003 | 2012-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 2012-10-15 07:06:00.000 | 2012-10-15 20:12:00.000
00004 | 2012-10-22 00:00:00.000 | 2012-10-22 07:12:00.000 | 2012-10-22 19:15:00.000
```

**I need Output:**

```
EmpNo | ChkDate | ChkIn | ChkOut
00001 | 2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2012-10-01 07:21:00.000 | 2012-10-01 12:21:00.000
00002 | 2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2012-10-01 08:13:00.000 | 2012-10-01 19:55:00.000
```

THANKS FOR YOUR TIME.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM filesTA tf
WHERE  tf.EmpNo NOT
IN (
SELECT lr.EmployeeRun
FROM LeaveRecord lr
WHERE lr.StartDate = '2012-10-01'
)
```